# Can not bind the domain to AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, nanohttpd

I use EC2.
So far I have been using `Elastic IP` to get a static IP.
And I was able to bind the Htttp server to an AWS prepared domain like `ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com` and run it.

This time, I got a domain from an external site and set the direction of that domain to `Elastic IP`.
And I was able to confirm that the IP was actually switched.

However, the HTTP server running on EC2 stopped starting.
This server is made in Java, and it raises the exception `java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address`.

This Http server specifies the host and port to bind to when it starts, but this time I had made a change to make the host a new domain obtained from the dive site.

(from `ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com` to `xxxxxxx.com`)

Why does this exception occur?
(BTW, the Http server uses the NanoHTTPD library)

Comment: We need a bit more information.  Your Java server shouldn't know anything about the actual IP.  Nano doesn't look like it's alive anymore but you still shouldn't need to bind to the real IP.

Comment: Have you added the IP-address or the domain name onto the Java core of configurations? 
I ask this because instances themselves arent really aware of the Public IPs or Elastic IPs attached on them. From the OS pov, they are only aware of the private IP-addresses.